# MYBATIS Generatedkey Tag doesn't seem to work in Spring MVC

Tags: hsqldb, spring-mybatis

//Im using spring mvc , mybatis and hsql to implement a CRUD operation

//for generating id im trying to use Generated value tag but it doesn't seem to be //generated

I'm new to mybatis and am supposed to submit this as my internshp project pklease help

```
<insert id='addEmp1' parameterType='Employee'
    useGeneratedKeys='true' keyProperty='E_ID'>

            INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."EMPLOYEE"(
    "ADDRESS",
            "AGE",
            "CITY",
            "DEPT",
            "FNAME",
            "LNAME",
            "SALARY",
            "STATE")

    values(
            #{address},
            #{age},
            #{city},
            #{dept},
            #{fname},
            #{lname},
            #{salary},
            #{state})
</insert>
```

//The Bean Class

```
 public class Employee {

public Employee() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private Long e_id;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is Mandatory")
private String fname;

private String lname;



@NotNull(message = "Age is Mandatory")
@Range(min = 18, max = 99, message = "Age should be between 18 and 99")
private Integer age;

@NotNull(message = "salary may not be empty")
@Range(min = 1)
private Integer salary;

@NotBlank(message = "")
@NotEmpty(message = "Select one Department")
private String dept;

@NotBlank(message = "Select atleast one state")
private String state;

@NotBlank(message = "Select atleast one City")
private String city;

@NotEmpty(message = "At least one Skill is required")
@Valid
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> skills = new ArrayList<String>();

private String address;
```

//the stacktrace shows the id to be null (It should be auto Generated)

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint 
violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10226 table: EMPLOYEE column: 
E_ID

### The error may exist in com/jamocha/DAO/EmployeeMapper.xml


### The error may involve com.jamocha.DAO.EmployeeDAO.addEmp1-Inline

### The error occurred while setting parameters

### SQL: INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."EMPLOYEE"(   "ADDRESS", "AGE", "CITY", 
"DEPT", "FNAME","LNAME", "SALARY", "STATE")    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

### Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity 
constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10226 table: 
EMPLOYEE column: E_ID] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint 
violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10226 table: EMPLOYEE column: 
E_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem caused by the attribute you have in your insert tag. Please try the following mapping instead

```
<insert id='addEmp1' parameterType='Employee' useGeneratedKeys='true'
    keyProperty='e_id' keyColumn='E_ID'>

    INSERT INTO "PUBLIC"."EMPLOYEE"(
            "ADDRESS",
            "AGE",
            "CITY",
            "DEPT",
            "FNAME",
            "LNAME",
            "SALARY",
            "STATE")

    values(
            #{address},
            #{age},
            #{city},
            #{dept},
            #{fname},
            #{lname},
            #{salary},
            #{state})
</insert>
```

Please note the changes of keyProperty (case sensitive) and keyColumn attributes.
For me information please refer to http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#insert.2C_update_and_delete for more details.